# Limits problem how to find counterexample

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

Let $f$ and $g$ be functions with domain $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x) = b$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow b} g(x) = c$. Prove or disprove that $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} (g \circ f)(x) = c$.

I cannot seem to find a counterexample for this. However, based on what I know about limits, I also cannot see why it would be true.

Comment: Here is a hint.  The statement is true when $g$ is continuous at $b$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

You may want to draw it to see what happens.

- Let $g(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & x \neq 0 \\ 0 & x=0 \end{cases}$
- Let $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Now, you have $\lim_{x\to 0}g(x) = 1$ and $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x) = 0$.

What is $\lim_{x\to 0}g(f(x))$?